Is there a hack to use typeof with an expression?
I want to use TypeScript's typeof operator with an expression.
I know from the docs that it is by design not achievable, but was wondering if a hack exists which will allow me to exceed the limitation to achieve this:
function a_function<T>()
{
    return {} as any
}

const a_value = a_function<true>()

type UsingConst = typeof a_value                // OK
type WithoutConst<T> = typeof (a_function<T>()) // Is there a hack ?

Playground

Edit I've added the complete use case to avoid confusion on why I could use this hack. The goal is to standardize my quick test when I develop types.

Is the method described in the doc what you're looking for, or something else? // Meant to use = ...

I have added the usecase in the question to avoid confusion, but yes it is what i'm trying to achieve, this is why i need a hack

You really want "instantiation types" but TS doesn't provide those. typeof on an expression is also forbidden, as you've seen.  See ms/TS#52035 for an authoritative answer. The only hack I can think of abuses generic classes like this approach. (Note your complete use case isn't viable. You cannot call is_type_of<T, Ref> for generic T, Ref; you made that a compile error on purpose, so even if you solved this, you'd hit that.) Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an a. If not, what's missing?

The hack works indeed but not for my usecase unfortunatly as you point it out as Equals cannot work prior to specefying the types T and Ref- neverthe less write the solution as i can +1 and validate it

TypeScript doesn't have instantiation types, where you can specify the type argument of a generic function without calling it and see the resulting function type. If it did you could maybe write ReturnType<typeof a_function<T>>. But you can't. There are instantiation expressions, so you can write const f = a_function<true> and ReturnType<typeof f>, but that doesn't help get rid of a const. And as you saw you cannot write typeof expr for an arbitrary expression expr, so typeof a_function<T>() also doesn't make sense to TypeScript.  This is described in microsoft/TypeScript#52035, and it's currently a design limitation or missing feature or set of missing features.
The only hack I can think of is to abuse generic classes, because this gives you a handle to use a generic type argument in the place you need it.  Maybe:
class Ugh<T> {
    x = a_function<T>()
}
type WithoutConst<T> = Ugh<T>["x"]

So here we've initialized a field x of Ugh<T> to be the result of a_function<T>(). So now we can just index into Ugh<T> to get the type of its x property and it works.
Playground link to code
